# Convert all non-url strings to lowercase in a multiline block of text

Tags: php, regex, parsing, preg-replace-callback

I use this code to convert an entry to lowercase except urls.

```
$fragments = preg_split( '/[ \n]/', $entry);
foreach ($fragments as &$fragment) {
    if(filter_var($fragment, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) === FALSE)
        $fragment = mb_strtolower($fragment, "UTF-8");
}
unset($fragment);
$entry = implode(' ', $fragments);
```

The problem is fragments are divided by space or newline both as seen above, but they are all imploded by space only.

Is there any solution for imploding it according to the splitting method?

Comment: Check the [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback)

Comment: what's the input and the desired output ?

Answer (score 0):

1. I agree with @zerkms, use `preg_replace_callback()` to perform a custom function upon each qualifying substring.
2. By inverting the logic of your original pattern to to match non-whitespace substrings, you can avoid the challenge of gluing your split string with the appropriate whitespace character.
3. I am showing how to overwrite `$entry` with the updated string, but you can, of course, instantly `echo` the return value if you like.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/3UrNf))

```
$entry = <<<ENTRY
Bob 1 https://www.example.com#Anchor
Joe 2 joe@exAmple.com
Sam 3 http://examPle.org
Ian 4 www.Example.net
Öna 5 eXample.info
Eve 6 Heart_in_a_Blender
ENTRY;

$entry = preg_replace_callback(
             '/\S+/',
             function($m) {
                 if (!filter_var($m[0], FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)) {
                     $m[0] = mb_strtolower($m[0], "UTF-8");
                 }
                 return $m[0];
             },
             $entry
         );
echo $entry;
```

Output:

```
bob 1 https://www.example.com#Anchor
joe 2 joe@example.com
sam 3 http://examPle.org
ian 4 www.example.net
öna 5 example.info
eve 6 heart_in_a_blender
```